# Git reading ignore rules from some other file

Tags: git, drupal-7

Any new files which I add to my git repo were getting automatically ignored. After searching and applying some suggestions what I found that my newely added file was ignored by this rule
docroot/sites/default/settings.php:562:/**         heeo (This is the name of my directory "heeo")

This I found by executing this command "git check-ignore -v *"

Now my problem is why git is reading the rule from this file which I have in my drupal project. It is reading the beginning of a multi line comment which is equivalent to ignore all inside a directory when placed in .gitignore .

Comment: Is `core.excludesFile` specified in your `git config -l`?

Comment: @ElpieKay yes it is showing  core.excludesfile=docroot/sites/default/settings.php

Comment: Then it's the cause. You can add an ignored file by `git add -f <filepath>` if necessary.

Comment: @ElpieKay I got the cause, thanks to u, but if could please tell how can I remove this from config and will it prevent other untracked files from being ignored

Comment: You can run `git config -e` and remove it, or just run `git config --unset core.excludesfile`. But I'm not sure if it's okay for your project. If it is the rule every contributor must follow, then you'd better not remove it. If you are in teamwork, ask the administrator for help.